# How to Find the Differential of $y=2\sin^2(x)$ when $x = \pi/4$ and $dx = 0.49$

Tags: calculus, trigonometry, derivatives, pi

I am wondering how to find the differential of $y=2\sin^2(x)$ when $x = \pi/4$ and $dx = 0.49$.

I realize that I should be finding the derivative of $y=2\sin^2(x)$, which is $4\sin(x)\cos(x)$. And, I think I should sub $\pi/4$ into the derivative of the equation to get $2$. However, I am not sure what is meant by $dx = 0.49$.

Can anyone please explain what this equation is asking, and how I may find the answer to it?

Comment: I believe your derivative is $dy/dx$ and your differential is $dy$. Does that help?

Comment: @JohnMolokach Oh, I thought derivative and differential meant the same thing (i.e., they are both dy/dx). But, I suppose that differential would be $dy=4\sin(x)\cos(x)dx$, while the derivative would be $(dy)/(dx)=4\sin(x)\cos(x)$. Is this correct?

Comment: The "differential" is best understood as a [*differential form*](http://math.umn.edu/~bpawlows/teaching/324sp12/ec3.pdf).  If you consider $f$ to be a $0$-form, then you can apply a different type of derivative to it: the exterior derivative $d$.  So $df$ is the exterior derivative of the function $f$.  We can evaluate $df(x)$ but using the relation $df(x) = \frac{df(x)}{dx}dx$, where $\frac{df(x)}{dx}$ is the regular derivative (and not a fraction of differentials as it may appear).  So in your case $dy(\pi/4) = \frac{dy(\pi / 4)}{dx}dx = 4\sin(\pi /4)\cos(\pi/4)(0.49)$.

Comment: @Kelsey Yes. You have to be careful about treating $dy/dx$ as a fraction, but as noted in the other comment, you can separate the quantites to write what is called a differential form.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

differencing $y = 2\sin^2 x,$ you get $dy = 4 \sin x \cos x \, dx.$ now subbing $x = \pi/4, dx = 0.49$ gives you $dy = 2 \times 0.49 = 0.98$

Comment: Oh, I thought derivative and differential meant the same thing (i.e., they are both dy/dx). But, I suppose that differential would be $dy=4\sin(x)\cos(x)dx$, while the derivative would be $(dy)/(dx)=4\sin(x)\cos(x)$. Is this correct?

Comment: @Kelsey, that is correct. derivative is a ratio of two small things; differential is one of the small things.